# How to connect our app to an portable bill or ticket printer

Tags: ios7, printing

Hi this is my first app so I don't have more experience. I have designed an invoice app now I want my app to print the bill. But I have no idea how to connect my app to a portable printer. Can anyone please suggest me any portable printer available in market. I have searched in net but I can't find any product. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to connect to your phone your printer would have to have bluetooth printer to connect to your phone. It doesn't matter what you buy. If you go in to settings see if bluetooth is on and if not turn it on and if your app doesn't see it well there's something wrong with the app it's self.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but obviously there is a need for some framework to support a particular printer in the app. If a printer got AirPrint support then we can print. But I can't find any portable printer with that feature.